# THREE.JS VideoTexture Safari Frame Loading

Tags: video, three.js, safari

I'm currently working on a project where I am using 5 video's for multiple meshes (~ around 20). I attach each video to multiple meshes. After that I am setting everything on play().

```
this.frames.forEach((frame, i) => {
  const geometry = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(this.ratio * frame.scale, frame.scale, 32)
  const name = i
  const x = this.setFramesPosition(frames, frame, i)
  frame.src.currentTime = 0.1
  frame.src.load()

  for (let i = frame.clips - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    const texture = this.createTexture(frame)
    const material = this.createMaterial(frame, texture)
    const plane = this.createPlane(geometry, material, frame, name, x, i)
    canvas.scene.add(plane)
  }

  frame.src.play() 
 })
   
 createTexture(frame) {
  const texture = new THREE.VideoTexture(frame.src)
  texture.minFilter = THREE.LinearFilter
  texture.magFilter = THREE.LinearFilter
  texture.format = THREE.RGBFormat
  return texture
 }
```

On Chrome and Firefox everything is working fine as you can see on the left of this video (https://vimeo.com/450794717). But on Safari (on the right), you can see that it only plays the first 5 video's of the row. The rest of the video's are buggy frames that are blinking.

Does anybody know how to fix this bug on Safari?

Comment: You might want to report this as a bug to WebKit https://webkit.org/reporting-bugs/. BTW: Instances of `VideoTexture` have a RGB format and linear filtering by default. So there is no need for setting it.

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed my issue by creating a texture for each frame, not for each clips.

```
this.frames.forEach((frame, i) => {
  const geometry = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(this.ratio * frame.scale, frame.scale, 32)
  const texture = this.createTexture(frame)
  const name = i
  const x = this.setFramesPosition(frames, frame, i)

  for (let i = frame.clips - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    const material = this.createMaterial(frame, texture)
    const plane = this.createPlane(geometry, material, frame, name, x, i)
    canvas.scene.add(plane)
  }

  frame.src.play()
})
```